# Possible to continue script execution if require_once fails?

Tags: php

Is it possible to continue PHP script execution even if require_once fails? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple - it's not

use `include_once()`

require() is identical to include() except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will halt the script whereas include() only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which allows the script to continue.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Comment: Warning: include_once([path]/../mymain.php?do=cron) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [path]/mine.php on line 113

Comment: are you sure that script halts? because this warning is expected

Comment: Yea I put an echo immediatly under it which doesn't execute.  I must be making a mistake somewhere else...

Answer (score 1):

Use `include_once` instead.  You can also check the result and react appropriately

```
$success= include_once('foo.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Current answer is incorrect, yes it is possible. This is how

```
try{
  require_once(__DIR__.'/../core.php');
}
catch( Exception $e ){
  require_once(__DIR__.'/../../core.php');
}
```

Any error can be caught by putting it in a try/catch block where you can address the problem if you know a solution. For example, this block as a whole is still effectively a require, and is more effective than using string manipulation or scanning directories. If your script doesn't have a hard dependency of course, just use include_once